# Regex pattern in C# for Regex.Replace() in C#

Tags: c#, regex, implementation

I have a string

```
string str1 = "SELECT * FROM A INNER JOIN B JOIN C JOIN A INNER JOIN B LEFT JOIN C";
```

I want to Replace the **JOIN** not followed by **INNER**, **LEFT**etc  with **\nJOIN**

My desired output is

```
SELECT * FROM A INNER JOIN B \nJOIN C \nJOIN A INNER JOIN B LEFT JOIN C
```

I am a novice C# programmer and what I wanted to use is

```
var pattern = NOT IN("INNER" || "OUTER" || "LEFT") + @"\b"+ "JOIN";
var output = Regex.Replace(str1, pattern, "\nJOIN", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Here I stuck with implementing the **NOT IN("INNER" || "OUTER" || "LEFT")** with RegEx.

Can you please help me in this regard. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [Regular Expression Language - Quick Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Can anyone please tell me why people are down voting :( ? Point it out to me so that I can edit the question.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, thanks for the link.

Comment: @NoorAShuvo my guess is three things: 1) you didn't provide your attempts so far. 2) you asked for a tutorial link which is considered off-topic for SO. 3) people are left with the impression that you didn't try to figure it out on your own before asking.

Comment: Pay attention to the *negative lookahead* there. Also, alternation and word boundaries are of interest.

Comment: Be careful: *regular expression* instead of *parser* can change query's *meaning*: `select * from TableA -- join TableB on TableA.Id=TableB.parent_id` will *uncomment* the join

Comment: Another difficulty is in *followed by*: `...left /*la-la-la*/ /*bla-bla-bla*/ join...` or `select 'just join string'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
string str1 = "SELECT * FROM A INNER JOIN B JOIN C JOIN A INNER JOIN B LEFT JOIN C";
string result = Regex.Replace(str1, @"(?<!INNER)\s+JOIN", "\nJOIN");
//result: SELECT * FROM A INNER JOIN B \nJOIN C \nJOIN A INNER JOIN B LEFT \nJOIN C
```

I used this handy website to learn how to do it: [regex101](https://regex101.com/)

Remember to use the **quick reference** search in the lower right to find the character or expression you need (e.g. I searched "Not" in your case)

UPDATED: to make it more robust and allow 1 to n amount of blank spaces between INNER and JOIN

Comment: If only I add a *space* (let alone a *comment*: `/*la-la-la*/`) after `INNER`: `INNER  JOIN` the routine starts adding `\n`

Comment: Another counter example: `string str1 = "SELECT * FROM JOINT_VENTURE";` or even exacerbated `string str1 = "SELECT * FROM [MY JOINT VENTURE]"`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko as for having extra spaces I agree, I fixed that by adding \s+. I've never seen comments inside a SELECT query (is this a common thing?). I appreciate your advice though

Comment: @Innat3: in case of *complex query* comments are quite common. Simple *join* example: `select a, b from TableA cross join /*cartesian - every A to every B*/ TableB`